# Rename "bitmonerod-commands" as "monerod-commands"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[bitmonerod](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitmonerod) is now [monerod](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerod)

Should [bitmonerod-commands](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitmonerod-commands) change to [monerod-commands](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerod-commands)?

Alternatively, should the [bitmonerod-commands](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitmonerod-commands) tag be removed in favor of using the more general [monerod](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerod) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [monerod](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerod) is already one of the most popular tags, I like your proposal to use a more specific tag [monerod-commands](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerod-commands) as the [bitmonerod-commands](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitmonerod-commands) replacement